# how do i put spaces between the items in a list view

Tags: android

I want to places spaces between items in a listview. I am using a drawable divider so if I use the android:DividerHeight the actual drawable increases in size and I don't want that I just need to put spaces between the items. So can anyone assist me in this??

Comment: are you trying padding ??

Answer (score 0):

In each view element of the list, simply add [marginTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_marginTop). E.g.

```
<ListView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    </EditText>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be margin, padding or use a custom item

```
android:padding="50dp"
android:layout_margin="50dp"
```